# How can I peek into a Mesage from a Filter?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, servlet-filters

I tried to use a `javax.servlet.Filter` to peek into a message.

```
public void doFilter( ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
     BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
     if ( reader.markSupported() ) {
         reader.mark( contentLen );
     }
     String content = reader.readLine();

     // search some pattern

     if ( reader.markSupported() ) {
         reader.reset();
     }
     chain.doFilter( request, response );
}
```

The servlet that finally receives the request throws this exeption:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getReader() has already been called for this request
```

Which is correct behaviour according to the javadoc.

My questions is how can I read the content of the input-stream anyway?

I also tried `ServletInputStream is = request.getInputStream();`

Comment: Could clone the request and then look at the clone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but you could probably

- read all the bytes from the request input stream and write them to a byte array,
- construct a buffered reader over this byte array to read what you want in the filter,
- construct a [`HttpServletRequestWrapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html) which overrides `getInputStream()` to return a stream over the byte array,
- pass this wrapper to the filter chain.

Comment: Thank you, copying seems to be the only way.

Comment: This opens an easy `OutOfMemoryError` vulrenability hole. A hacker could just send a request body which is larger than the server's available heap to take the server entirely down. Look at how Apache Commons FileUpload handles large file uploads by storing it partially in memory and remaining on temp disk. Or just look for a different solution depending on the concrete functional requirement.

Comment: @BalusC: interesting. Tomcat uses a maxPostSize set to 2 megabytes to avoid this problem with regular request body parsing. I guess the OP should do the same thing, and throw an exception once the number of read bytes is more than X MBs. I wonder if web frameworks which automatically transform a JSON-encoded request body to an object have this kind of maximum, or if they're open to the same vulnerability.

Comment: If a self-respected API, it should do.

Answer (score 1):

Following the aproach from @JB Nizet led to this code:

```
public class HttpServletRequestCopy extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    private final byte[]       buffer;

    private ServletInputStream sis;

    private BufferedReader     reader;

    public byte[] getBuffer() {
        return buffer;
    }

    public HttpServletRequestCopy( HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        super( request );
        final ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        copyStream( request.getInputStream(), byteArrayOutputStream );
        buffer = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    }

    @Override
    public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
        if ( reader == null ) {
            String characterEncoding = this.getCharacterEncoding();
            if ( characterEncoding == null ) {
                reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( this.getInputStream() ) );
            }
            else {
                reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( this.getInputStream(), characterEncoding ) );
            }
        }
        return reader;
    }

    @Override
    public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        if ( sis == null ) {
            final ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream( buffer );
            sis = new ServletInputStream() {
                @Override
                public int read() throws IOException {
                    return bais.read();
                }
            };
        }
        return sis;
    }

    private void copyStream( InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
        final byte[] bytes = new byte[ 1024 ];
        int length;
        while ( (length = input.read( bytes )) != -1 ) {
            output.write( bytes, 0, length );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*ServletRequest.getInputStream()* and *ServletRequest.getReader()* are either-or, so if either has already been called, the other one will fail. You can use a simple try-catch to navigate around this:

```
try {
    request.getInputStream();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    // someone already called getReader(), so use it instead
    request.getReader();
}
```

**NOTE!** It is not specified that the stream or reader should be resettable, so if you consume any bytes off it, they will not be anymore available to any filters or servlets further in the chain.

Comment: It's hard to tell all those JSPs and other servlets to do that. No, this is not really a feasible "workaround" which will probably also mess up the character encoding when really implemented somehow.